# How to deal with fast sequential clicks in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a `ListView` with items that will navigate on click.

The list item has two text views, which have the following click handlers:

```
private OnClickListener playClickListener() {
        return new OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TestActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
             } 
        };
    }
```

Unfortunately this leads to TestActivity firing up as many times as the user clicks intbetween int loading.  I tried setting the click handers to `null` with `setOnClickListener(null)`.  However when I navigate back to the activity the list item is then no longer clickable.

Is there a nice work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use `startActivityForResult()`.

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_MAKE_CLICKABLE = 1;

private boolean mAlreadyClicked = false;
private OnClickListener playClickListener() {
    return new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mAlreadyClicked) return;
            mAlreadyClicked = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TestActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_MAKE_CLICKABLE );
         } 
    };
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_MAKE_CLICKABLE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        mAlreadyClicked = false;
    } 
}
```

and in your TestActivity you can override finish to do the following:

```
@Override
public void finish() {  
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
    super.finish();
}
```

This will lead to the click being fired only once until the next activity returns and "re-enables" the click functionality.

**--OR--**

You could be boring and keep the boolean and simply "reset" it on onResume():

```
private boolean mAlreadyClicked = false;
private OnClickListener playClickListener() {
    return new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mAlreadyClicked) return;
            mAlreadyClicked = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TestActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent, REQUEST_CODE_MAKE_CLICKABLE );
        } 
    };
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAlreadyClicked = false;
}
```

You *should* really be boring, but it's always fun to use cross Activity callbacks. :)

Comment: Thanks!  I went for the boring way - was hoping there was something more elegant.  Works fine though - Thats the main thing!